# How to pull a variable from an array file in python?

Tags: python, arrays, variables

I'm using somebody else's code that stores a sequence in an array in python:

```
blah=array(<Sequence: 2TPS (2TPS refined (label=2TPS) refined (label=2TPS, rowocc>=0.8, colocc>=0.8)[0]; length 196; 196 residues and 0 gaps)>, dtype=object)
```

I can print the sequence using the following:

```
print blah
    SVYFIMGSNNTKADPVTVVQKALKGGATLYQFREKGLTGEARIKFAEKAQAACREAGVPFIVNDDVELALNLKADGIHIGQEDANAKEVRAAIGDMILGVSAHTMSEVKQAEEDGADYVGLGPIYPTETKKDTRVQGVSLIEAVRRQISIPIVGIGGITIDNAAPVIQAGADGVSMISAISQAEDPESAARKFREE
```

However, I want to be able to call this sequence and save it to a text file without using the "print" function. I've tried blah[0] etc, but nothing works.

Comment: This just says "invalid syntax". Are you using numpy, scipy or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your array is a numpy array (dtype...)

Have you already tried just parsing it to a string?

```
result = str(blah)
```

or

```
result = blah.tostring()
```

another option is to parse it to a list

```
result = list(blah)
```

Now you should be able to use the variable `result` and write it to a file or do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to save a python list to a text file and you want to read it 
later.

You can write list to text file as:

```
with open('filename', 'wb') as a:
        pickle.dump(blah, a)
```

You can  read the file and store each lines in a list:

```
with open('filename', 'rb') as a:
    blah = pickle.load(a)
```

you can access your data like:
blah[0]

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean [array.tofile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html)
or looking at Bob's answer [numpy.ndarray.tofile()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html)?